# Unexpected end of input when using fetch API with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch-api

i'm trying to fetch JSON from the give API: https://dummy-api.com/api/drivers

i've included `mode: no-cors` to the fetch() function. However, now i've gotten

> Unexpected end of input

which doesn't fetch anything.

I've also tried doing `res.text()` before parsing as JSON and it didn't work either.

Here are my codes:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
const [drivers, setDrivers] = useState([])
const [error, setError] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(
                    'https://dummy-api.com/api/drivers',
                    {
                        mode: 'no-cors'
                    }
                )
                const data = await response.json()
                console.log(data)
            } catch (error) {
                setIsLoading(true)
                setError(error)
                console.log(error.message)
            }
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])
```

so the output im supposed to see should be a JSON form like this:

```
{"pickup_eta":6,"drivers":[{"driver_id":"0-ikkpyhyjg9","location":{"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"bearing":229}}]}
```

thank you!

Comment: FYI `console.log(fetchData())` won't give you anything because fetchData is an async process.

Comment: thanks, removed it already but it doesn't resolve the "Unexpected end of input" issue. @Andy

Comment: That api url doesn’t seem to exist or return any data. Are you sure that is the correct url?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky hi, i cant put up the actual API. so i had to put in a dummy one

Comment: try adding ```'Accept': 'application/json',``` and ```'Content-Type': 'application/json',```

Comment: Please check the url directly on the browser. it is not reachable if it is internal serve try with mode:"cors"

Comment: @PrakashS i get `Access to fetch at 'https://dummy-api.com/api/drivers' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.` when using mode:'cors'. hence, i was using mode:'no-cors'. and yes, im able to access the url directly on browser! :)